# Build reports dynamically in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have data in my database table which looks similar to the data below :

```
   Time       Name Sales
   Aug-11      A     33
   Aug-12      B     34
   Aug-13      C     31
   Aug-14      D     39
   Sep-11      A     99
   Sep-12      B     34
```

The requirement is that I need to build a report for A details ,another report for B details ,and another for C details and so on. There Could be a D and E added to the database table next month and some more data the month later...

I want to know if there is a way that I can create the reports dynamically , rather than creating a report for A, B and C now and then going into the report and creating another report for D and E next month and soo on..

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a report with a parameter @Name  , Create a Drop down List using query something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
FROM Table_Name
```

for user to select A, B or C and in parameter properties you can choose it to be a multiple selection and create a query something like

```
SELECT Time, Name , Sales 
FROM Table_Name 
WHERE (Name IN (@Name_Pram))
```

You will have to create 2 Data sets one for the drop down list from where users will select Name parameter, selected value(s) will be passed to the above query , One report will show details for any selected values.

Comment: Hey Muhammed Ali ! Thanks for your answer .. but I do not think parameters will help me in the current scenario. I need to create reports for A, B and C and any additional names added to the database table in the future. I do not have a requirement here to choose a Name, I need to create different reports for each name contained in the database table

Comment: Hi Courage, it sounds to me like a report parameter is exactly what you need, is there a reason you cant use them?, and when you say different, how different ?

Comment: @Courage well than you need to define the term "Different" a bit more as it is not clear what you mean by different report.